# Using a cylinder as a D3 die

Tags: probability, geometry

A DM (dungeon master) is developing a game from the book "A Mote in God's Eye" and would really like to have a D3 die (left hand, right hand, gripping hand).  One could use a six-sided die and just devote two sides to each choice, but the DM really wanted a die that had only three sides.

Then the DM realized that a coin is two-sided, but if it was made thicker, it would land more often on its 'edge', which could be the third choice.  That even made sense for the game, as the third hand, the gripping hand, is that 'other' choice, a bit different than the other two.

The DM realized that a coin always (well, almost always) lands on either face, whereas a long cylinder would rarely land on either of its end faces.  So there must be some height of a cylinder, based on its diameter, such that if it is tossed like a coin, there is an equal change of it landing on its top face, its bottom face, or its thick edge.

What would this height be?

Comment: While this question is off-topic here as "engineering", there is a plethora of unusually shaped dice dX for almost every imaginable X out there, start e.g. at https://skullsinthestars.com/2017/03/09/the-geometry-of-weird-shaped-dice/ and see the "crystal dice" section for a d3.

Comment: This is a nice question, and should be solvable, though it may be more of a math question. I suspect that it has to do with the distance to the centre of mass: the cylinder will topple if the perpendicular from the centre of mass falls outside its base. One could possible assume all orientations of the cylinder to be equally likely, and then as a second step check whether it would topple over or not... Would be nice to try this out using python.